# How to update a static css file in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

**Problem**

When a user updates a theme in front-end, an API in my Nodejs would presumably update the static `css` file in a public folder set up by `Express`, so that when pages are served again with `<link href="public/theme.[userId].[hash].css"`, the user will see the new style previously made.

---

I'm building with `React` styled with `styled-jsx`, then server-render a certain set of components into HTML and sent to front-end to be styled by the dynamic stylesheet.

My naive way to solve this in Nodejs is, I would need a way to extract the component's css(with Webpack?), then use `fs` to overwrite the particular static css file so that it will cache bust next time it's required.

How would you design the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't make changes in CSS file based on the theme. You make different CSS files based on the themes and then call the appropriate CSS file.

Comment: Thanks. I struggle to figure out how to implement that. Tell me if I'm on the right direction: 1) When user updates theme, use webpack to extract the css into a new css file, 2) Use nodejs's fs to write that content to a new file in my static folder.?

Comment: Why do you even need webpack for this? User's theme I'm assuming will be saved in their profile. While loading your page, just use an if condition and set that theme based on the profile data.

Comment: Cuz if I have the theme as a .css file, then browser or cdn can cache it, like a bootstrap.min.css file. However, in my case, the theme is subject to changes by users, so how do I handle that in the backend...

Comment: Identify each theme by key value pair in a profile. As soon as the user logins, use css based on that key value pair fetched from the profile.

Comment: Yes, but how would you extract and update when a dynamic theme is modified from front-end?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say. Please explain with an example. If you're saying what if user changes theme while using the application? Save the theme in a state variable. Whenever the state is changed, react rerenders it.